# how to pass values from foreach loop to another method

Tags: c#, methods, foreach, unity-game-engine

What I need to do is get foreach values from one method called `private void ReceiveData()` and send them to another method `void Update()` . How to do that in c#?

```
private void ReceiveData() 
    {

       IPEndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.217"), port);
       client = new UdpClient(remoteIP);
        while (true) 
        {
           try 
            {
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                int nIndex = 0;
                foreach(SignalIndex si in xmlreader.cdpSignals)
                {
                     x= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 0);
                     y= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 4);
                     z= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 8);
                     alpha= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 12);
                     theta= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 16);
                     phi= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 20);

                //  xmlreader.unityGameObjects[nIndex].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x,y,z);
                //  xmlreader.unityGameObjects[nIndex].transform.Rotate(alpha,theta,phi);   
                }

            }
            catch (Exception err) 
            {
               print(err.ToString());
            }

        }

        client.Close();
    }


    void Update() 
    {
        foreach(GameObject go in xmlreader.unityGameObjects)
        {
            go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x,y,z);
            go.transform.transform.Rotate(alpha,theta,phi);
        }
    }
```

There are 2 methods and I need to get the values in foreach from ReceiveData() and instantiate them in method Update(). All variables in foreach from ReceiveData() are public, but they all takes 0 in Update().

Comment: How do you mean, "get foreach values from one method"?

Comment: more context needed. It is unclear what you mean, especially since both methods take no parameters and return `void`.

Comment: @MarcGravell , Hi! I updated my question with a more context :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2:

Documentation for ReaderWriterLockSlim: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

```
struct CoordData
{
    public float X, Y, Z, Alpha, Theta, Phi;
    public int NIndex;
}

private List<CoordData> coordDataList = new List<CoordData>();
private ReaderWriterLockSlim lockObj = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

private void ReceiveData() 
{

   IPEndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.217"), port);
   client = new UdpClient(remoteIP);
    while (true) 
    {
       try 
        {
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

            int nIndex = 0;
            foreach(SignalIndex si in xmlreader.cdpSignals)
            {
                 x= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 0);
                 y= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 4);
                 z= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 8);
                 alpha= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 12);
                 theta= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 16);
                 phi= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 20);

                 lockObj.EnterWriteLock();
                 try
                 {
                     coordDataList.Add(new CoordData() { X = x, Y = y, Z = z, Alpha = alpha, Theta = theta, Phi = phi, NIndex = nIndex });
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                     lockObj.ExitWriteLock();
                 }

                 nIndex++; //I'm assuming you want to do this here otherwise you'll be changing the same object in the array every time  
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err) 
        {
           print(err.ToString());
        }

    }

    client.Close();
}

void Update()
{
    lockObj.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        foreach (CoordData data in coordDataList)
        {
            xmlReader.unityGameObjects[data.NIndex].localPosition = new Vector3(data.X,data.Y,data.Z);
            xmlReader.unityGameObjects[data.NIndex].Rotate(data.Alpha,data.Theta,data.Phi);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lockObj.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer but I doubt it will work as I've just seen the comments on the answer below. Do you need to call Update() as soon as you receive the data? Or can you store the values in an array or something and then read them out in Update()?

Comment: my Update() couldn't take any parameters when I call the Update() in another script I get an error which says that I need to call this from main thread and I dont know how to pass x,y,z,alpha,theta,phi to Update()

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've got an errors: error CS1914:  Static field or property `UDPReceive.CoordData.NIndex' cannot be assigned in an object initializer; error CS0122: `UDPReceive.CoordData.NIndex' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Have you had chance to try this?

Comment: Thank you very much it works! But there is one more issue, while running it prints out following "System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Write lock cannot be acquired while read lock is held
  at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLock (Int32 millisecondsTimeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterWriteLock () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
" Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: You can try adding a timeout on to the write locking. Where you have `lockObj.EnterWriteLock();` you can replace this with `lockObj.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout);` where `timeout` is the number of milliseconds you want to wait before giving up trying to get a lock, you could try 50 for a start, it's up to you how long you think it's acceptable to wait. 50 milliseconds would mean roughly 20 writes per second.

Answer (score 0):

The way foreach works is as follows:

In your method (`ReceiveData`) you wil loop through some sort of method. Then from that loop you can call the other method (`Update`). However, you will have to pass these variables around. Your methods currently are void and don't ahve any arguments.

I suggest the following:

```
private void ReceiveData()
{
    var data = GetMyDataFromSomewhere(); // data should be an IEnumerable of some sort

    foreach (MyDataItemType dataItem in data)
    {
        Update(dataItem);
    }
}

private void UpdateData(MyDataItemType dataItem)
{
    // Do some update to dataItem here...
}
```

After your new update with more code, there is some more info to work with. Apparantly, you are setting some fields/properties in the class (`x`, `y`, `z`, etc). And the update method will use those to update something.

Then why not just call `Update()` from either within your `foreach` loop, or after the loop if it only has to be done after it has been set:

```
foreach(SignalIndex si in xmlreader.cdpSignals)
{
    x= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 0);
    y= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 4);
    z= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 8);
    alpha= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 12);
    theta= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 16);
    phi= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, si.index + 20);

    UpdateData(); // Just call it!
}
```

Comment: my void Update() can't take any parameters :(

Comment: well you could create the parameters?

Comment: when I calling my Update() its shows up an error: get_transform  can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

Comment: In that case, we definately need more context. Are you using some sort of library? Does this class inherit from something? What error does it exactly give? For example, I don't even *see* a `get_transform` anywhere... Please add more info to your question.